# Troubles uploading my portfolio (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) to Heroku, what requirements should I check?

Tags: heroku, deployment, portfolio, visual-web-developer

I'm encountering difficulties when trying to deploy my web portfolio, which is developed in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, on Heroku. When I attempt to upload the page from Visual Studio Code, I get a blank screen instead of my website. I'm confident that I'm missing something crucial in the process.

What are the essential requirements I should verify before uploading my portfolio to Heroku? Are there specific configurations I need to set up on Heroku or in my Visual Studio Code project to ensure it functions correctly? Are there common issues I should consider when making this migration? I appreciate any advice or guidance you can provide to resolve this issue and make my portfolio work smoothly on Heroku. Thank you!

I am already aware that Heroku has transitioned from being a free service to a paid one. I have already subscribed to a paid plan. Previously, I had launched a sentiment analysis application with Flask, and everything worked correctly. However, when attempting to view my portfolio, I was not successful.